# Does iMessage use SMS?

Tags: iphone, messages

I have a Vodafone plan in Germany that covers all local texts and data. I also get data for free when I am in the UK. I used iMessage in the UK and was charged by Vodafone because text messages abroad are not free.

How exactly does iMessage work? I thought it only used data but Vodafone insists that I sent SMSes while abroad.

Comment: It might be beneficial to start with [Apple’s User Guide on this topic](https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/set-up-messages-iph3d039b67/ios)